# Symfony 2 : number_format Twig Extension

Tags: symfony, twig, number-formatting

I tried to use that Twig Extension :

```
<?php

class Twig_Extensions_Extension_Number extends Twig_Extension
{
    /**
* Returns a list of filters.
*
* @return array
*/
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array('number' => new Twig_Filter_Function('twig_number_filter'));
    }

    /**
* Name of this extension
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Number';
    }
}

function twig_number_filter($number, $decimals = 0, $dec_point = '.', $thousands_sep = ',')
{
    return number_format($number, $decimals, $dec_point, $thousands_sep);
}
```

I've created a folder Twig/Extension in my bundle and put the Extension inside.

Then I modified the services.yml file to use it :

```
services:
    project.twig.extension:
        class: App\AppBundle\Twig\Extension\NumberExtension
        tags:
            -  { name: twig.extension }
```

And tried to use the filter in some view like this :

```
{{ 50|number(2, ".", ",") }}
```

But I got the following error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function twig_number_filter() in
>   C:\wamp\www\myapp\app\cache\dev\twig\de\cc\18a233a6ed21bfc26e40b6654c9c.php
>   on line 83

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the `getFilters` method:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array('number' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'twig_number_filter'));
}
```

`Twig_Filter_Function` is calling the function from the global namespace, `Twig_Filter_Method` with `$this` passed will call your class method.